# SignalR sending string with html tags

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, signalr

I setup signalR on my website, but I'm having a problem when sending a string with html tags.

Example:

```
This is a test -> works!

This is a <b>test</b>! -> doesn't work :'(
```

Here's the error on javascript console:

```
POST https://localhost:44300/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionT…TfDVg5lmkPA7Zur7GmPN8chMYAp35FNw8wDOzte1HlpW37N1nGVUlMYiuYqP_BEmKq0F7yta20 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
send jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
i.transports._logic.ajaxSend jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js:10
r.transports.serverSentEvents.send jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js:10
i.fn.i.send jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js:10
r.fn.r.invoke jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js:10
proxies.discussion.server.addNewDiscussion hubs:90
(anonymous function) modules.main.js:214
p.event.dispatch jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
g.handle.h jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
```

Anyone already had this problem before? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you debug the server and see whats the error that was  thrown? you can get it from the Application_Error method

Comment: I have the same problem. Interestingly, this phenomenon does not exist in IE10.

Comment: I was using textarea container to display the signalR messages. When i replaced it with a div container the problem disappeared.